# How to make Tweenmax animation will work only particular viewport?

Tags: html, scrollmagic, gsap

I am new to tween max, in my project, I am using tween max with scroll magic. its horizontal scroll and I have five different sections. so for each section, I added different types of tween max animations and those animations will work only I reach the viewport. but now all the sections animations are working when I refresh the page itself. if I scroll to a particular section the animation already done. how to fix this?

This is my tween max code:(this is for only second section)

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
var tl7 = new TimelineMax();
tl7.from("#section02 #title2", 0.5,{y:10, opacity:0, ease: Sine.easeIn});
tl7.from("#section02 #trigger--title2", 0.3,{y:10, opacity:0, ease: Sine.easeIn});
tl7.from("#choose1 span", 0.3,{y:10, opacity:0, ease: Sine.easeIn});

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement:"#section02",
  triggerHook: "onEnter"
})
.setClassToggle('#section02', 'animate')
.reverse(true)
.setTween(tl7)
.addTo(controller);
```

My HTML:

```
   <div class="wrapper" id="js-wrapper">
    <div class="sections" id="js-slideContainer">
      <section class="section" id="section01">
        <span class="section__title" id="title1">Section One</span>
        <span id="trigger--title1"></span>
      </section>
      <section class="section" id="section02">
        <span class="section__title" id="title2">Section Two</span>
        <span id="trigger--title2">sub</span>
      </section>
      <section class="section" id="section03">
        <span class="section__title" id="title3">Section Three</span>
        <span id="trigger--title3"></span>
      </section>
      <section class="section" id="section04">
        <span class="section__title" id="title4">Section Four</span>
        <span id="trigger--title4"></span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

For reference, I included the Codepen URL - https://codepen.io/sankarsam/pen/MWKBYwJ

if anyone knows this please help me.

Comment: Hey Sankar. We at GreenSock highly recommend using the official GSAP scroll plugin: [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger). It has [a built in method](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.matchMedia) to make setting up and destroying scroll animations based on media queries.

Comment: Hey, @ZachSaucier this is really awesome...it's really interesting. thank u so much...